# Angular - error installing library fullcalendar

Tags: angular, compiler-errors, fullcalendar, angular6, angular-module

I am trying to install this calendar library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-fullcalendar), following the steps however, I get the following errors:

> ```
> ERROR in node_modules/angular2-fullcalendar/node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/async.d.ts(8,10): error TS2305: Module '"<...>/node_modules/rxjs/Subject"' has no exported member 'Subject'.
>    node_modules/angular2-fullcalendar/node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/async.d.ts(9,10): error TS2305: Module '"<...>/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no exported member 'Observable'.
>    node_modules/angular2-fullcalendar/node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/async.d.ts(10,10): error TS2305: Module '"<...>/node_modules/rxjs/Subject"' has no exported member 'Subject'.
>    node_modules/angular2-fullcalendar/node_modules/@angular/core/src/util/lang.d.ts(8,10): error TS2305: Module '"<...>/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no exported member 'Observable'.
>    node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(1,15): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/Observable'.
>    node_modules/rxjs/Subject.d.ts(1,15): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/Subject'.
> ```

Chrome console gives me the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Can't construct a query for the property "myCalendar" of "HomeComponent" since the query selector wasn't defined.

I have followed the steps of installing it via npm, imported `CalendarComponent` in my app.module.ts and declared it in my declarations under `@NgModule`.

I then created a component called home.component.ts and copied the following in, as instructed.

```ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PageEvent } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  // MatPaginator Inputs
  length = 100;
  pageSize = 10;
  pageSizeOptions: number[] = [5, 10, 25, 100];

  // MatPaginator Output
  pageEvent: PageEvent;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  setPageSizeOptions(setPageSizeOptionsInput: string) {
    this.pageSizeOptions = setPageSizeOptionsInput.split(',').map(str => +str);
  }

  calendarOptions:Object = {
    height: 'parent',
    fixedWeekCount : false,
    defaultDate: '2016-09-12',
    editable: true,
    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    events: [
      {
        title: 'All Day Event',
        start: '2016-09-01'
      },
      {
        title: 'Long Event',
        start: '2016-09-07',
        end: '2016-09-10'
      },
      {
        id: 999,
        title: 'Repeating Event',
        start: '2016-09-09T16:00:00'
      },
      {
        id: 999,
        title: 'Repeating Event',
        start: '2016-09-16T16:00:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Conference',
        start: '2016-09-11',
        end: '2016-09-13'
      },
      {
        title: 'Meeting',
        start: '2016-09-12T10:30:00',
        end: '2016-09-12T12:30:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Lunch',
        start: '2016-09-12T12:00:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Meeting',
        start: '2016-09-12T14:30:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Happy Hour',
        start: '2016-09-12T17:30:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Dinner',
        start: '2016-09-12T20:00:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Birthday Party',
        start: '2016-09-13T07:00:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Click for Google',
        url: 'http://google.com/',
        start: '2016-09-28'
      }
    ]
  };
}
```

I added this selector in:

```html
<angular2-fullcalendar [options]="calendarOptions"></angular2-fullcalendar>
```

Imported this in my main style.css:

```css
@import "fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.css";
```

I added the calendar as view child.

My angular.json has the following:

```json
    "angular2-fullcalendar": "^1.0.19",
    "ap-angular2-fullcalendar": "^1.6.4",
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because Angular 6 is utilizing RxJS **v6**.  That calendar package you are trying to use is very out of date and is using an older version of RxJS where the directories are different.
What you can do is try `npm install rxjs@6 rxjs-compat@6 --save` in the product directory, which will basically install a compatibility layer for dependencies that have not yet been updated to RxJS **v6**.

 Hope this helps.

[More Info](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md)

---

As far as your the error in your comment goes, here's how I installed/used this package.

In project directory:

```
npm i ap-angular2-fullcalendar jquery --save
```

To use jquery and fullcalendar in conjunction, you need the typings:

```
npm i --save-dev @types/jquery@3.2.7
```

Import jquery and the calendar component to app module.  Declare the calendar component.

```
import * as $ from 'jquery'
import {CalendarComponent} from "ap-angular2-fullcalendar/src/calendar/calendar";

...

declarations: [CalendarComponent],
```

For the rest, I just used the code you provided - only changing this line:

```
calendarOptions:Object = {
    height: '600px',
    ...
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/3991)

Comment: Got the following error now: `ERROR in ./node_modules/angular2-fullcalendar/src/calendar/calendar.ts
Module build failed: Error: ...\node_modules\angular2-fullcalendar\src\calendar\calendar.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
The missing file seems to be part of a third party library. TS files in published libraries are often a sign of a badly packaged library. Please open an issue in the library repository to alert its author and ask them to package the library using the Angular Package Format.`

Comment: @JonnySprouse As it says, I think the package is just poorly packaged and it may be a good idea to find a different calendar package but let me see if i can help.

Comment: Brilliant, all fixed. Thanks.